# PHP fetchAll PDO::FETCH_OBJ and json_encode returns invalid JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

I try to fetch some data from my MySQL database by using `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` and `json_encode` but it doesn't work since I added an `DATE`-field in the MySQL table.

This is what my code looks like:

```
$app->get('/api/teams', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";

try {
    $db = new db();

    $db = $db->connect();

    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $teams= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($teams);

   } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
   }
});
```

Before I added the `DATE`-field, it worked perfectly fine and it was returning an array with a bunch of objects. Now it returns no data at all. Even though, when I forexample do call `/api/teams/25` - I receive the correct data, even with the date-data. So it"only" fails when I want to receive all teams/data at once.

Can someone tell me whats wrong and how to fix it?

I can also tell that I tried to do this:

```
foreach($teams as $team){
    echo json_encode($team);
}
```

But this returned invalid JSON data, which was a bunch of Objects without comma separation

**EDIT**

My DB SCHEMA looks like this,

```
id (int(11), primary_key, auto_increment)
team ( varchar(255) )
country ( varchar(255) )
league ( varchar(255) )
creation_day ( date )
```

** EDIT 2 **

The invalid JSON which the `foreach`-example returns, looks like this:

```
{"id":"27", "Bayern München", "country":"Germany", "league": "Bundesliga, "creation_day": "2016-10-14"} {"id":"28", "Borussia Dortmund", "country":"Germany", "league": "Bundesliga, "creation_day": "2016-10-14"}
```

..and so on

Comment: can you post your schema?

Comment: @JeffPuckett what schema?

Comment: database schema

Comment: @JeffPuckett see the edited question/post

Comment: You need to post an example of the "bad" data, otherwise we can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Sammitch check the edited post

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not emitting one JSON document, but several that are just smashed together. That's not valid. Just do this:

```
echo json_encode($teams);
```

Comment: ehhh... but thats what I do?

Comment: You do that inside a loop, you produce N JSON documents, not a singular valid JSON document. Generally when producing JSON results you're allowed one call and one call only to `json_encode`, so if you need to restructure your data to make it work in JSON you do that before making the call. In your case you seem to have an array so it's fine to pass it in directly, no need to iterate.

Comment: in the post, I wrote "I also tried"... ´echo json_encode($teams)´ returns nothing - since I added the `Date`-field in the MySQL table

Comment: It's not clear why it didn't work the first time, because if your iterator version works then it absolutely should.

Comment: As a quick test, try and comment out any code not related to producing JSON results, then enable bits until you find the exact failure.

Answer (score 0):

> PDO::FETCH_OBJ: returns an anonymous object with property names that correspond to the column names returned in your result set
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

I suspect your use of `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` is the source of your problem. I would suggest you change that to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` if you're just looking to output the entire result as JSON.

So your code example would look like:

```
$app->get('/api/teams', function(Request $request, Response $response) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teams";

try {
    $db = new db();

    $db = $db->connect();

    $stmt = $db->query($sql);
    $teams= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // <-- This changes
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($teams);

   } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
   }
});
```

The reason I believe this is your issue is because JSON requires a certain format so if you were not getting any output from your `echo` then chances are your JSON was invalid. If you want to test you can check what you receive back from `json_encode`:

> **json_encode**
>
> Returns a JSON encoded string on success or FALSE on failure.
>
> http://php.net/json_encode